# How to change background-image with nth-child property?

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code. From row onwards it is repeated 2 more time inside the class contenedor, only thing that changes is the href url and de class in i(an icon).

```
<div class="contenedor">
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <center>
                <div class="zoom espacio">
                    <div class="contorno">
                        <a href="carta.html">
                            <i class="fas fa-shopping-bag fa-5x"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>Prueba</p>
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>

<!–– Second time––>
<!–– Third time ––>
</div>
```

And this CSS. What it does is that when I hover over the element I change the background image of contorno. I would like to change the image of the 3 elements individually with the nth-child property:

```
.contorno:hover{
background-color: none;
background-size: cover;
    background-image: url("someURL");
}
```

And this is what I've tried but it's not working:

```
.contenedor .row .col-lg-12 .zoom .espacio .contorno:hover:nth-child(1){
background-image: url("someURL");
}
```

Thank 4 the help.

Comment: Sorry, I think my english wasn't good. What I meant was that the repeated items are children of .contenedor.

Comment: the `.zoom .espacio` part of your selector is incorrect. It should be `.zoom.espacio`

Answer (score 0):

You would need to select the `nth-child` of `.contenedor` which is your `.row`.

```
.contenedor .row:nth-child(1) .col-lg-12 .zoom.espacio .contorno:hover {
  background-image: url("someURL");
}
```

```css
.contenedor .row:nth-child(1) .col-lg-12 .zoom.espacio .contorno:hover {
  color: red;
}

.contenedor .row:nth-child(2) .col-lg-12 .zoom.espacio .contorno:hover {
  color: blue;
}

.contenedor .row:nth-child(3) .col-lg-12 .zoom.espacio .contorno:hover {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="contenedor">
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <center>
                <div class="zoom espacio">
                    <div class="contorno">
                        <p>
                            First
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <center>
                <div class="zoom espacio">
                    <div class="contorno">
                        <p>
                            Second
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <center>
                <div class="zoom espacio">
                    <div class="contorno">
                        <p>
                            Third
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also your selector was incorrect. The `.zoom .espacio` should be `.zoom.espacio` because `.espacio` is not nested inside `.zoom`... they are the same element.

I would also recommend removing the `<center>` tag because it is deprecrated.

Comment: You were right with the selector and I modified it. I tried your solution, but it is only changing the first one, the second and the third are unaffected. I just edited my question a bit and clarified that the background image is in the class contorno. Thank you

Comment: you would need need to create styles for the other children `.row:nth-child(2)` and `.row:nth-child(3)`. did you do that?

Comment: @DavidGuzmánZazueta Does [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bfjpz590/) do what you want?

Comment: Exactly what I want, I've tried it but it is still changin only the first one. I've deleted the center tag as you said and still not working. I'll check my code to see if I am doing something wrong